# Contando a quantidade de vezes que um determinado número se encontra em uma tupla

Tags: python, tupla

O programa deve receber 4 números do usuário, e armazenar em uma tupla. Então informar a quantidade de vezes que o número 9 foi digitado, e a posição do número 3, caso ambos tenham sido digitados. Porém o número de vezes da 0, independente de quantas vezes eu digite o número 9, e a linha referente a posição do número 3 dá erro.
[Segue a forma como fiz:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ah6VW.png)

Comment: [Não coloque imagem/link do código](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052), coloque-o em texto. Enfim, `input` retorna uma string (mesmo se vc digitar números, os dígitos serão tratados como caracteres), então o número `9` é diferente da string `'9'`. Vc precisa converter para número (`int(input(...))`). De qualquer forma, é um código ineficiente porque primeiro verifica se o número está, e depois conta (ou seja, no fundo são 2 loops implícitos, a resposta abaixo tem o mesmo problema). Dá pra fazer tudo em um loop: https://ideone.com/Bj0Y29

Answer (score 0):

Olá, eu reescrevi o código e consegui o resultado que você buscava. os únicos erros no seu código foram o int não estar no input, e na estrutura do if, onde o " if 3 in tupla: " precisava estar dentro do " if 9 in tupla: " assim como o " else: print(' O número 3 não foi digitado ') " para a posição do 3 aparecer quando ambos o 9 e o 3 estiverem na tupla. aqui está como eu fiz:

```
tupla = tuple(int(input('digite um número: ')) for _ in range(4))

if 9 in tupla:
     print(f'O número 9 se repete {tupla.count(9)} vezes')
     if 3 in tupla:
          print(f'O número 3 esta na posição {tupla.index(3)}')
     else:
         print('O número 3 não foi digitado')
else:
    print('O número 9 não foi digitado')
```